# can't translate to any other language using gettext php function

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

I use a WAMP server on Windows and make a test project.
I have these files in the website folder:

> C:\wamp\www\project\locale\ar_EG\LC_MESSAGES\messages.po
>   C:\wamp\www\project\locale\en_US\LC_MESSAGES\messages.po

Below is the PHP Code:

```
$language="en_US";
$encoding = "UTF-8";
putenv("LANG=".$language);
setlocale(LC_ALL,$language);
$domain="messages"; // name of PO file
bindtextdomain($domain,"Locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $encoding);
textdomain($domain);
echo gettext("name");
```

Above code is working fine.
When I try to replace `en_US` with `ar_EG` it also displays the translation for `en_US`, and when I try to remove the `en_US` folder and try again it displays the `msgid` not `msgstr`.

I searched and found that there is a problem with `setlocale` on the Windows platform, but I need a solution for it to run on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setlocale() on Windows has issues.

From [setLocale() in PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php):

> Windows users will find useful information about locale strings at
>   Microsoft's MSDN website. Supported language strings can be found in
>   the » [language strings documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and supported country/region
>   strings in the » [country/region strings documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

You might try to use `$language = 'english-us';` instead of `$language = 'en_US';`.

I'm not sure about the language code for `ar_eg`, maybe `Arabic_Egypt` or `Arabic_Egypt.1256`.

If that doesn't work, you still have the option to use a PHP library, which implements gettext,
like https://github.com/oscarotero/Gettext or https://launchpad.net/php-gettext.

Comment: thanks @Jens-Andre Koch but unfortunately , Arabic Egypt not works, could you please tell me how to use PHP library.

Comment: Please check the usage example out: https://github.com/oscarotero/Gettext#usage-example

Comment: For me the error was type `fr_fr` instead of `fr_FR`

Answer (score 0):

I made it work on windows with following code:

```
$locale = 'en_US';

if(!defined('LC_MESSAGES') || !setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale)) {
    putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
}

$domain = 'messages';
$path = "C:\wamp\www\project\locale";
$codeset = 'UTF-8';

bindtextdomain($domain, $path);
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $codeset);

echo gettext("name");
```

Comment: hey @bitWorking , i have no problem with en_US , my code is working fine when i use en_US.
the problem happened when i use ar_EG , do u have any idea ?

Comment: yes i try ar_EG but it echo the english language , what is the result when u try ar_EG ??